# jQuery scroll content with navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone tell me how to scroll the content.
For example I have a link like this

```
<a href="#">content3</a>
```

When the user click that link I would like to scroll the content to `div content3`.

Can someone tell me how to do this using jQuery?

Here is my full code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">content1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">content2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">content3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">content4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="content1" class="content1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="content2" class="content2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="content3" class="content3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="content4" class="content4">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Eric You can scroll the page with CSS?

Comment: @Eric How is that CSS? That's pure HTML...and default browser behavior. And there's already an answer with that explanation...

Comment: woaah, my mind went blank, CORRECTION... html. my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) :

Example :

```
<a scrollTo="content3" href="#">click me to scroll to the div "content3"</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        $("#container").animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).attr('scrollTo')).offset().top }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery to do this - simply use `href="#content3"` to scroll to the element with an `id` of "content3".

Comment: I completely agree. Other than animating the scroll, this is how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has scrollTop and scrollLeft methods to do this.. if it is merely vertical scrolling, then scrollTop(yVal) will do the trick

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are attempting to do, but go check out [wowslider.com](http://wowslider.com)

Answer (score 0):

Using the $('body').scrollTop atribute like so:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    var element = $('#content1'),
    elemTop = element.offset().top, // You get the element top to know where to move the window
    windowTop = elemTop + 20; // You can add some pixels so the element dont be shown on the very edge
    $("html, body").animate({
           scrollTop:  windowTop // Animate the change so it doesnt seem invasive
    }, "fast");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('a').on('click', function (){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).text()).offset().top},
    'slow');
});
```

See this [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cCwjq/1/)

Greetings...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your markup it appeared you wanted to use the anchor text to determine where to scroll. If you click the `content1` link it will scroll you to `<div id="content1">`.

```
$('.nav ul li a').click(function(){

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).text()).offset().top
    }, 2000);

});
```

Heres a fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG3zh/

Answer (score 0):

In order to scroll with HTML you need to set the `href` of the anchor `#+'id of element'` you are scrolling to.

Example:
I want to scroll to `<div id="scrollHere">Hello World</div>`
using an `anchor` tag or `a` use the code, `<a href="#scrollHere">Click Me!</a>`